# Android Studio 1.1.0 - Error while adding Fabric Crashlytics to app

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've been trying to add Crashlytics to an app I'm developing on Android Studio 1.1.0 with no luck. I've added the Fabric plugin to Android Studio and when adding my app, the Crashlytics library is not recognized.

Here is the code added by Fabric:

```
...
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics; // Error here
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric; // Error here
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); // Error here
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}
```

And here are the errors:

```
C:\Workspace\Projects\AndroidG\Borgertip\borgertip\src\main\java\dk\gis34\borgertip\activity\MainActivity.java
Error:(12, 31) error: package com.crashlytics.android does not exist
Error:(16, 29) error: package io.fabric.sdk.android does not exist
Error:(67, 31) error: cannot find symbol class Crashlytics
Error:(67, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Fabric
```

Can a kind soul figur out why this doesn't just work, like it does on Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have these lines in your **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
   // ...
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
   }
}
```

and this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
       // ...
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.14.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why the install process in Android Studio is så relativly painfull compared to Eclipse, when everything else is much better?

Comment: I have all that but it still doesnt resolve. Most of the time, i have to delete the project and all files and restart the whole process again until everything works as it should.

Comment: I'm still getting error `Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3`. Any suggestion ?

Comment: SweetWisher, Are you sure, you have added correct maven repository?